# Special Case of Summation

Tags: summation, convention

Hello what would be the solution to the summation over the range from 1 to 0?

$$ \sum_{1}^{0} = ? $$

My guess is -1 or 0, but I can't find any reference to this case.

Comment: What are you summing?

Comment: You need an argument in the summation, e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^{0}1$. In such a case,it's widely accepted that the sum is zero

Comment: I know two definitions of $\Sigma$. Using one of them, the answer is trivially zero. Using the other, which is the recursive definition, the symbol you ask about is meaningless, it doesn't equal anything.

Comment: Does it really matter what the argument is in this case?  If it helps lets go with $a_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the inductive identity

$$\sum_{i=m}^{n+1}a_i=\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+a_{n+1}$$

to get

$$\sum_{i=1}^0 a_i=\sum_{i=1}^1 a_i-a_1=a_1-a_1=0$$

Of course, that assumes the usual rules apply to such a case. That is a weak assumption, so such sums as yours should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

If $m > n$, then: 
$$
\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n} a_k = 0.
$$

Comment: An empty sum is zero, and if the upper limit is less than the lower limit the convention tends to be that the sum is empty. But the convention is different for integrals, where swapping the limits changes the sign.

Answer (score 0):

Summation of what? Anyway, whatever it is, the answer is $0$. Because the sum is not well-defined, so it will not be performed.